# Changing table's width after load in Handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I'm trying to add a button that will make the table get 100% width. I can see that the settings do change when checking with `table1.getSettings()`, but the table doesn't change.

html:

```
<div id="table1" class="table"></div>
<button id="fullWidth">Strech to full width</button>
```

css:

```
#table1 {width: 100%;}
```

JS:

```
var myData = Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(10, 5);

var container = document.getElementById('table1');
var table1 = new Handsontable(container,
                          {data: myData,
                           stretchH: "none",
                           colHeaders: true
                          });

Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(fullWidth, 'click', function () {
    table1.updateSettings({
        stretchH: "all"
    });
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asafusan/z0g2zz05/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, and this may be the intended behavior since there is a different way of doing it. When expanding your table, it may make more sense to update the actual width of your table and set the `stretchH: "all"` from the beginning.

It's a little cleaner since you can imagine the user could have modified the width of the columns and then just wanted to expand the table's size rather than the column widths. Regardless, check this [modified version](http://jsfiddle.net/u6wpwuaL/) of your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! How can I set it to take 100% of screen width?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "screen". If you want, you could use the `width` of `window` so something like `$(window).width()`.